# Phaser.js: How to get or remove all sprites in one scene

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-engine, phaser-framework

I used to handle a group of sprites by push them into an array or sprite group which is build-in class in the Phaser. But I am seeking another simple way could get or remove all sprites in an scene. Does anyone have any idea to resolve this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scene has a property `children` ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html#children__anchor))

You can get all **Sprites**,  with the command:

```
// where this = the current scene
let allSprites = this.children.list.filter(x => x instanceof Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite);
```

And then remove/destroy them all, like this:

```
allSprites.forEach(x => x.destroy());
```

Just iterating through the list of sprites, and calling the `destroy` function on each object.